# What is the getApplicationContext() method?

Tags: android, methods

I am busy learning android and I came across the `getApplicationContext` method. I didn't really understand what it was used for and what it's purpose is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. check the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Context object is used across the application to do many things like access resources that the Android OS has allocated for you.

- using getSystemService, you get the handle of your service and you can do wonders.
- pass the context object to your classes to do Toast

It is useful and powerful if used correctly.